# Hide and show content Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a form for users who have forgotten their login data. There are three radio buttons and when the user clicks on a radio button and clicks 'OK', the whole content hides and a new form is shown for the option they have chosen. Below the html:

```
<div id="MainContent">
    <form ng-submit="">
        <label><input type="radio" name="dataForgotten" id="unForgotten"/>Forgot username</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="dataForgotten" id="pwForgotten"/>Forgot password</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="dataForgotten" id="bothForgotten"/>Forgot both username and pw</label>

        <input type="submit" value="OK">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I make this happen with Angular? I have very little experience with Angular, so I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to achieve this.Try this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Use ng-show and ng-hide with ng-model .

Comment: Yo can take a look on ``ng-if`` directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve the desired effect.

1. Using `ng-if`
2. Using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

The difference is in this, `ng-if` removes/recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on a `Boolean` expression i.e. `true` or `false` values.
On the other hand `ng-show` just hides the portion based on the value of the expression. It sets the display of that the part of the DOM to none.

For your case I would favor `ng-if` so that only the required part of the DOM is loaded into the app at the right time. Some have argued that by changing expressions on the web-inpsector, one could enable or disable an `ng-show` block.

Here is the **Edited** code. I have included a plunker. here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/JB4LAgo9rqtPnPZHpwWr?p=preview

```
  <label><input type="radio" value="unForgotten" ng-model="dataForgotten"/> Forgot username</label>
<br/>

<label><input type="radio" value="pwForgotten" ng-model="dataForgotten"/>Forgot password</label>
<br/>
<label><input type="radio" value="bothForgotten" ng-model="dataForgotten"/>Forgot both username and pw</label>


<div ng-if="dataForgotten == 'unForgotten'">
    <!-- If Username Forgotten then Content goes here-->
    Username Forgotten
</div>


<div ng-if="dataForgotten == 'pwForgotten'">
    <!-- If Password Forgotten then Content goes here-->
    Password Forgotten
</div>

<div ng-if="dataForgotten == 'bothForgotten'">
    <!-- If Both Forgotten then Content goes here-->
    Both Forgotten
</div>
```

Here is the explanation on the docs as regards `ng-if`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

While here is the documentation for `ng-show` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget ngSwitch for a third built in directive option.

Comment: @jme11 Yes, I will add an ng-switch explanation. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show` for this. The directive evaluates a boolean condition and shows the content when true, so to hide one section and show another you just need the inverse.

```
<div ng-show="!completed">
    First Section
</div>

<div ng-show="completed">
    Second Section
</div>
```

On your `$scope`, you'll have a bool `completed` property (or whatever you want to call it) and you can change this in your controller when the button is clicked using `ng-click`.

```
<button ng-click="changeCompleted()">Show/Hide</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.changeCompleted = function(){
    $scope.completed = !$scope.completed;
}
```

*Note you could also shorten this part by performing the assignment directly in the `ng-click` directive.

Here's a working [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jfkbj10u/).

[ng-show docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Also, if you'd like to make sure a radio button is checked before allowing the button to be clicked, have a look at [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) which allows you to conditionally disable/enable your button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it in plain javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="hide('MainContent')">Close</a>

function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="MainContent">
<form ng-submit="formsubmit(dataForgotten)">
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="dataForgotten" id="unForgotten"/>Forgot username</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="dataForgotten" id="pwForgotten"/>Forgot password</label>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-model="dataForgotten" id="bothForgotten"/>Forgot both username and pw</label>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>

<form name="secondForm" ng-show="submited">
</form>

</div>
```

//controller code

```
 $scope.submited=false;
 $scope.formsubmit = {
//form value insert code here
 $scope.submited=true;
};
```